# How to change the fontsize of the Greek letters in formula?

Tags: beamer, fontsize

```
\documentclass[20pt]{beamer}  
\geometry{ papersize = {27cm, 21cm}}  
 \usepackage[english]{babel}  
 \usepackage{mathrsfs, booktabs, multirow}  
 \usepackage{amsmath}  
 \usetheme{Darmstadt}  

\begin{document}  
\begin{frame}  
 \frametitle{Maxwell Equation}\linespread{0.5}  

\huge  

\begin{equation}  
\vec A = \frac{\mu}{4\pi }\int_V {\frac{{\vec J(\vec x')dV'}}{r}}   
\end{equation}  
\begin{equation}  
\nabla \cdot \vec D =\rho  
\end{equation}  
\end{frame}  
\end{document}
```

I know the problem is relevant to the `\huge`. The Latin letters and the Greek letters do not increase in the same scale, but how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First two of commented now lines are the source of the problem. Horizontal spacing before `dV'` corrected.

```
%\documentclass[20pt]{beamer}  
\documentclass{beamer}  
%\geometry{ papersize = {27cm, 21cm}}  
 \usepackage[english]{babel}  
 \usepackage{mathrsfs, booktabs, multirow}  
 \usepackage{amsmath}  
 \usetheme{Darmstadt}  

\begin{document}  
\begin{frame}  
 \frametitle{Maxwell Equation}\linespread{0.5}  

\huge  

\begin{equation}  
%\vec A = \frac{\mu}{4\pi }\int_V {\frac{{\vec J(\vec x')dV'}}{r}}   
\vec A = \frac{\mu}{4\pi }\int_V {\frac{{\vec J(\vec x')\,dV'}}{r}}   
\end{equation}  
\begin{equation}  
\nabla \cdot \vec D =\rho  
\end{equation}  
\end{frame}  
\end{document}
```

[image]